# How to make a list of same elements which have common attributes values either using nightwatch.js or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ui-automation, ui-testing, nightwatch.js

I am working in nightwatch.js for automation testing for a web application, i am struggling to make a list of elements which has common values in their attributes, i am writing sample of elements as following.

**first three spans with common value of attribute: "data-annotation-id"**

```
<span class="my-note" data-annotation-id="580ss7ze8457f65119v54g32">first span</span>
<span class="my-note" data-annotation-id="580ss7ze8457f65119v54g32">second span</span>
<span class="my-note" data-annotation-id="580ss7ze8457f65119v54g32">Third span</span>
```

Above span attribute (data-annotation-id) value is: **"580ss7ze8457f65119v54g32"**

**second two spans with common value of attribute: "data-annotation-id"**

```
<span class="my-note" data-annotation-id="569dd7fe6092b62008b73b49">Fourth span</span>
<span class="my-note" data-annotation-id="569dd7fe6092b62008b73b49">Fifth span</span>
```

Above span attribute (data-annotation-id) value is: **"545yd6gd8265g7584g5s25"**

i tried following way to make collection of all spans which have common values of data-annotation-id attributes but its not working.

```
client.getText('.my-class', function(result) {
   client.expect.element('.my-class').to.have.attribute('data-attr').which.matches(/^something\ else/);
});
```

following syntax will not work because i don't know the value of data-annotation-id. so is there any way to get the desired result using either Nightwatch.js or javascript ?

```
client.expect.element('.my-class').to.have.attribute('data-attr').which.matches(/^something\ else/);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done using following line of code.

```
//using this line we are getting the number of spans in page.
client.elements('css selector','.my-class', function (noted) {        
  //on the basis of the number of noted i am finding attribute which has same value.
    noted.value.forEach(function (index) {
       client.getAttribute('.my-class', 'data-annotation-id', function(results) {
         console.log(results.value)
       });
    });         
});
```